# Using BOOST Spirit X3 with custom lexer

Tags: c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

How a X3 parser could use an already generated vector of tokens.
How the rules could be defined, having something like

```
enum class token { aa, bb, cc};    
auto rule = token::aa >> token::bb >> -token::cc;
std::vector<token> tokens{token::aa, token:bb, token:cc};
auto ok = parse(tokens.cbegin(), tokens.cend(), rule);
```

I'm interested to validate the input. The idea is to avoid any lexical analysis (x3::lit, x3::char_, x3::lexeme, x3::alpha, etc.) following the zero-overhead principle of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @sehe's reply, the implementation could be

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace my_parser
{
    enum class token
    {
        unknown,
        aa,
        bb,
        cc
    };

    namespace ast
    {
        struct my_seq
        {
            token m1 {};
            token m2 {};
            std::optional<token> m3 {};
        };
    }

    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct dummy_token_parser: x3::parser<dummy_token_parser>
    {
        using attribute_type = token;
        static const bool has_attribute = true;

        constexpr dummy_token_parser(const token tok): tok(tok) {}

        template <typename It, typename Ctx, typename A>
        bool parse(It& first, const It& last, const Ctx& /*ctx*/, x3::unused_type, A& attr) const
        {
            if (first != last && *first == tok)
            {
                attr = *first;
                ++first;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        token tok;
    };

    void parse_tokens(const std::vector<token>& input, auto& rule, ast::my_seq& my_seq_data, bool expected_result)
    {
        my_seq_data = {};
        const bool result = x3::parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), rule, my_seq_data);
        assert(result == expected_result);
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }

    using tp = dummy_token_parser;

    const x3::rule<struct my_seq_rule, ast::my_seq> my_seq {"my_seq"};
    const auto my_seq_def = tp(token::aa) >> tp(token::bb) >> -tp(token::cc);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(my_seq);
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(my_parser::ast::my_seq, m1, m2, m3);

int main()
{
    using namespace my_parser;

    ast::my_seq my_seq_data {};
    parse_tokens({token::aa, token::bb, token::cc}, my_seq, my_seq_data, true);
    parse_tokens({token::aa, token::cc}, my_seq, my_seq_data, false);
    parse_tokens({token::bb, token::cc}, my_seq, my_seq_data, false);
    parse_tokens({token::aa, token::bb}, my_seq, my_seq_data, true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done and brief. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

X3 doesn't support Lex and probably never will.

From here:

- [cannot get boost::spirit parser&lexer working for token types other than std::string or int or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191531/cannot-get-boostspirit-parserlexer-working-for-token-types-other-than-stdst/47232006#47232006)

> - using Lex makes most of the sweet-spot disappear since all "highlevel" parsers (like `real_parser`, `[u]int_parser`) are out the window. ***The Spirit devs are on record they prefer not to use Lex***. Moreover, Spirit X3 doesn't have Lex support anymore

I quickly searched an original quote for that here: https://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/spirit-general/thread/CACBJYpn4YvXpKoU68cWZD4PmGG0R4kfe%3DVDu5PuTkA7S79QAoA%40mail.gmail.com/#msg34551953

> There are no replacements for the lexer and I doubt X3 will ever have
> one, unless someone contributes some time and effort. I personally
> don't really use them, instead preferring on pure Qi. If you do it
> right, A pure Qi parser can be at par with or even outperform one with
> a lexer (anecdotal evidence only, not fully substantiated).
>
> The real advantage of X3 over QI is 1) in compile time and 2) in AST
> building. Parsing should be more or less the same. But, again in my
> experience, the most time consuming operations are in AST building,
> not parsing and not lexing.
>
> > Apologies in advance to the onslaught of questions and thanks in advance for any
> > insights.  I'd love to migrate our parser to X3 as it seems to provide many benefits over Qi.
>
> Again, pardon the delay in replying.
>
> Regards, 
>  -- 
> Joel de Guzman

When pressed, Joel elsewhere suggested to make your own simple token stream if your application really benefits from it, e.g. here https://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/spirit-general/thread/2A5FC1FD75EA0346A44CF4BD559664CD10CCEC%40SHEX-MB-09.ad.local/#msg34855244

Comment: Well, by lexer I mean lexical analysis (not Lex from Qi). I don't want to use x3::lit, x3::lexeme, x3::char_, etc. in rules. I will add more details to the question.

Comment: The verdict remains the same, but focusing on the downsides mentioned in my first quotation. Regardless, you *can* of course still use X3 with it, and the last link gives you an example, like here on COLIRU: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94ab3dae700b9049. The fact that Spirit Lex isn't supported is unrelated and just meant to support the sentiment that lexing generally is probably not a good match for Spirit.

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear to me. Looking into your sample code, I guess the solution is to create a simple x3::parser<token> that matches the token set in constructor.

Comment: Yes. I'm quite curious when this would be helpful (My imagination gravitates to examples where regular expressions would be a more natural fit. But I guess my imagination is just not trained enough :))

Comment: I was looking into the X3 generated lexical analysis and several regex objects were one-by-one evaluated which IMHO seems not so efficient. Therefore I created my own lexer with look ahead (https://github.com/KMX-Systems/smi-parser/blob/main/src/kmx/smi/lexer.cpp).

Comment: I meant regexes on the token sequence. Does X3 even use regex? I'm pretty sure it doesn't. (Perhaps you meant Lex, which *can* use it, but *specifically* supports statically generated lexing tables)

Comment: Hm, maybe I confused X3 generated code with the code generated by other tool. Nevertheless it could be that someone would like to use only syntactically rules, without any lexical rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255548/discussion-between-flaviu-and-sehe).